# VirtIO WiFi: unexpected full virtqueue

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, maui

i keep getting the same error when trying to build my .net maui app on visual studio using my android emulator, it keeps getting stuck at:
VirtIO WiFi: unexpected full virtqueue

Does anyone know how to fix this, i have been stuck for days now.

Thanks

I have tried using other emulators, i have tried deactivating hyperv and reinstalling it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.